# Is there a clean way for checking a cancellation request in BackgroundWorker without re-typing the same code over and over again?

Tags: c#

If I want to periodically check if there is a cancellation request, I would use the following code below constantly inside my DoWork event handler:

```
    if(w.CancellationPending == true)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        return;
    }
```

Is there a clean way for checking a cancellation request in `BackgroundWorker` in C# without re-typing the same code over and over again?

Please refer to the following code below:

```
void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    ...

    BackgroundWorker w = sender as BackgroundWorker;

    if(w.CancellationPending == true)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        return;
    }

    some_time_consuming_task...

    if(w.CancellationPending == true)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        return;
    }

    another_time_consuming_task...

    if(w.CancellationPending == true)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        return;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Maybe make your worker a state machine then you can just do a `while(!w.CancellationPending) { switch (_someSwitch) ... }`

Comment: Split the method to delegates. Let's say `Action[]` then foreach over the `Actions` inside the loop check `if(w.CancellationPending){e.Cancel = true; return;}`

Comment: For one you extract this into a helper method.

Comment: @usr you can't extract this to a helper, you can't have a method return out of a calling method so at best you could have would be `if(Foo(w,e)) return` slightly better but not really.

Comment: In what way is that not better? It converts 4 lines into one and abstracts unimportant stuff away. I think that is actually a reasonable solution while the OPs code is not.

Comment: With your solution you still have an important amount of repeated line. For each call to a `consuming_task` you have to insert your two lines

Comment: Thank you so much for your all help, my code looks much cleaner now ^_^, I'm still trying to make `MickyDuncan` and `usr` suggestions work to see how it will look like, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Use a while loop and delegates**

Add your task in a delegate list then test your condition in a loop.

You can use Action custom delegate to make this task easier (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx )

```
void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    List<Action> delegates = new List<Action>();
    delegates.add(some_time_consuming_task);
    delegates.add(another_time_consuming_task);

    BackgroundWorker w = sender as BackgroundWorker;    
    while(!w.CancellationPending && delegate.Count!=0)
    {
        delegates[0]();
        delegates.remove(0);
    }

    if(w.CancellationPending)
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```